# Adding custom where clause to AuthenticatesUser Trait Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

We have decided to use `Laravel` for a project as a test run for future frameworks and are really enjoying it. There is one issue we are having though.

We use the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` which handles `user authentication`. It works well. However, we have a column in the database called `userstatus` which could be a `0` or a `1`.

How do we inject this where clause into the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait?

I was thinking maybe something here (in my `LoginController`):

```
public function authenticated($request , $user){
  //if $user->userstatus != 1 logout and redirect to start page
}
```

But I dont know how to `logout` (im looking into that now) .

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic is right, you should redefine `login` and `authenticated` methods within `LoginController`.

your methods should be like below:

this method should be within your `LoginController.php`:

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {

        use AuthenticatesUsers {
            login as public loginParent;
        }

        protected function login(Request $request){
            $default = '/';

            $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->NotActive->first();

            if($user){
               return redirect()->intended($default);
            }

           return $this->loginParent($request);
        }


    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if($user->not_active) {
             $this->logout($request);
        }
    }
 }
```

then we should create `ScopeNotActive` method within `User.php` Model as Local Scope:

```
//User.php
     public function ScopeNotActive($query){

          return $query->where('userStatus', '!=', 1);
        }
```

and a Mutator to check if the user is not active:

```
// User.php
       public function getNotActiveAttribute(){

          return $this->userStatus != 1;
       }
```

Comment: my comment was for the prior solution can you tell me how to do a get request from inside the code you had prior `return redirect()->intended('/logout');` returns error as a POST request

Comment: I got your use case. I will update my answer, it's a little bit tricky

Comment: check my updated answer please. logout function will redirect you to start page, got a eye on the logic of it within AuthenticatesUsers trait